# Custom httpd logs on CentOS 7 server

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, logs

What specific commands or config need to be typed in order for a CentOS 7 web server running Apache httpd to generate tabular logs of all received http requests with the following four columns for each request:

1.) Response time (time response sent minus time request received)
2.) URL that was requested
3.) IP address of requesting client
4.) Browser of requesting client

These logs should be printed into a text file which can then be imported into other software for analysis.

Comment: #4 can only be inferred from the user agent string, which is not a true guarantor of correct information; anyone can reconfigure the UAS to reflect anything they like.

Comment: "three columns" of 4 items?

Comment: @DopeGhoti OK, but how does one get the other items to output into a text file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I edited the OP to include the fourth item but forgot to fix the reference that you mention. Do you have a suggested answer?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I fixed the typo that you pointed out. I have never worked with Linux log files before. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not personally aware of a way to do #1 but it seems to me that the rest can be handled by https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: #1 is impossible because there is no way to know how long it is between the transmission from the source (your Apache server) and the recipient without said recipient sending back an "okay I got your data at this time" response, which is not part of HTTP.